# ASP MVC: Is there a way to make some views/pages accesable only from the local network?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security

I'm developing an ASP MVC3 application and I have some views that are related to the security of the webpage (mostly creating users and groups). This page is only used by people inside the local network and even though they need to access with their user and password I would like to prevent people that are using the application from outside the network to access them as an additional security measure.

Is this possible with IIS and ASP MVC3?

Comment: You'll want to use the Membership/Roles API. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874239/best-approach-to-user-roles-with-an-intranet-application.

Comment: but it is easier for me to just use a web.config. I was not using the Membership/Roles API because the way that the security in this system is handled has been inherited from a legacy system that didn't blend very well with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can restrict access to a paths by IP address by using the web.config.

for example:

```
<location path="/localOnly/">
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
        <clear/>
        <add ipAddress="127.*.*.*"/>
        <add ipAddress="1.*.*.*"/>
        <add ipAddress="192.*.*.*"/>
      </ipSecurity>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
```

So just check on which local subnet your site is running, and add it.

Edit: I assume you already have the `"even though they need to access with their user and password"` part managed by just using the default mvc stuff right?

Comment: yes, I'm using Form Authentication, but I want to do this as an additional security measure

Comment: If you use Forms Authentication correctly, this is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: How do I do it using Forms Authentication then?

Comment: @jrummell When it comes to security, doing things that are "unneccessary" can be of great advantage. E.g. if the application were to suffer a privilege-escalation vulnerability or if an administrator's session could be compromised via, say, session fixation or cross-site scripting, then the added protection is there to continue to restrict access to the malicious user. This is known as *layered security* and is a Good Thing.

Answer (score 0):

How are your user's signing in?  Can you assign your users roles and prevent certain roles from accessing certain views?

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments from @Ron Sijm's answer, it looks like you want to do something like this.

Assign a role to users that need additional access (E.g. Admin), and then use the [Authorize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) attribute on actions that require this role:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ViewResult SecureAction()
{
}
```

This requires a Roles provider, however. Since you already have role management, I'd highly recommend implementing a [custom role provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx).